# I'm stuck in Seafloor Cavern

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm playing Pokemon Alpha Sapphire, I beat the Elite 4 and the Champion and now I am doing the Delta Episode.
So everything was going fine until I forget where Team Aqua's hideout is and accidentally went into Seafloor Cavern and now I can't get out. My *Gardevoir* has *Teleport*, but I did not bring it with me. And I don't have the TM *Teleport* either. If somebody finds a way to access the Pokemon boxes without being at a Pokecenter, please tell me. Somebody help!

Comment: The title is supposed to be: Stuck in seafloor cavern in Pokemon alpha sapphire

Comment: Why can't you get out? Or rather, why is that a problem?

Comment: You don't have Dig or an Escape Rope neither?

Comment: I think you're asking two different things here:
a) How to get out Seafloor cavern?
b) Is there a way to access Pokemon boxes without being at a pokecenter?

Can you open a new question and edit this one please?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options:

1. Search online for a map or [walkthrough](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire/Seafloor_Cavern) of the Cavern to get out.
2. Trade for a pokemon with [Dig](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Dig_(move)), [Teleport](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Teleport_(move)), or holding an [Escape Rope](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Escape_Rope).
3. Keep battling wild pokemon and [lose](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Black_out). Let all your pokemon faint. This will teleport you to the last pokecenter you used.

Comment: the last point would be very effective I think